# Mysql Alter glitch

Tags: mysql, insert-update, alter

Hey guys I was trying to alter my tables column to take
the current time stamp on creation, the error I'm getting
is `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( 'inspection_number' NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )' at line 1`

I was trying to use

```
ALTER TABLE `reports`  (
  `inspection_number` DATE NOT NULL default CURRENT_DATE
);
```

But I"m not seeing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems syntax is not correct. Use below :

if adding new column `inspection_number`:

```
ALTER TABLE `reports`  ADD COLUMN `inspection_number` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

if modifying existing `inspection_number` column:

```
ALTER TABLE `reports`  MODIFY COLUMN  `inspection_number` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Please specify datatype of column

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `MODIFY`

```
ALTER TABLE `reports`  (
  MODIFY `inspection_number` NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `reports` 
MODIFY `inspection_number` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have there is for when you create a table. When you modify a table and want to set a default value use:

ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY col_name col_type NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;